# My Subpage is not working,instead is showing 404 error(Wordpress Underscorer)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my underscorer theme,subpages are not working
I think think i declared it correctly

```
<a class="simple" href="Subpage/aboutme.php">About me</a>
```

Comment: Try to read more about WP template hierarchy https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ and how WP form the pretty URL using Rewrite API https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/.

Comment: remove `php` extention and create a page for `aboutme`

Answer (score 0):

To create a child page, you will need a parent page. If you already have a page that you would like to use as the parent, then you are good to go.

Simply go to the Pages » Add New to create a new page or edit an existing page in your WordPress admin area. On the right side, you will see Page Attributes box with Parent dropdown

[image]

In the Parent drop-down, you will see the list of all pages from your site. By default, it is set to ‘no parent’ which means this page is an individual page with no association. You need to select the page you want to use as the parent from the drop-down menu.

After that, you can just go ahead and save your changes. You can repeat this process to create more child pages.

To view child pages, you can go to the ‘Pages » All Pages’ page in WordPress admin area. You will see child pages listed under their parent page with a — prefix.

[image]

click on "view" page and put that link where you want.